# cassandra with play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, cassandra

I am trying to develop an application composed of 2 parts: a web service and an android app. I am planning to implement my web service with the java play framework and cassandra noSQL database.

I have been searching for it for 2 days, I still don't know how I can do it. I need to integrate a java client (hector) as a bridge between the app layer (Play2.0) and the database layer, but how to do it is not clear to me.

Right now, I can not connect cassandra from play; I can not make my queries which my app needs and I dont know whether I can use play2.x like previous versions (without scala language, just java and groovy template).

allright, I am trying to develeop a web service which can be scalable horizontal easly. Because there will be many request, possible most of them at same time, from mobile phones. That is why I choose play frmwork with cassandra (I got enough knowledge about play with relational DB in collage last semester). my web service will return some data to client according to location info of client. That is why search time from DB must be as short as possible.Actually I have already designed my DB model for cassandra, because I already defined what kind of queries my app needs and I got enough information about cassandra data model. I think the tools i choosed for my app is correct and can maintain it. shortly, I can not use cassandra with play like I used MySQL with play :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using Cassandra with Play, just as you could use it with Jetty or Tomcat or any other front-end.  Play has some tools available to abstract the usage of popular relational DBs, but these tools are not central to Play, and therefore you don't have to use them.  You will need to create your DAL to talk to Cassandra using the library of your choice (Hector, Astyanax, etc.), then use that DAL as you would in any other app.  Perhaps you are trying to do something different?  If so, please be very specific as to what you need to know.

Also, Play2 is quite different from the first version, so anything you've done in the older Play will need to be revisited.  It does still support Java, so that won't be an issue.

Comment: the comment i made was too long . That is why i added it to the question post above:)

Comment: My answer still stands.  You cannot use it like MySQL because it isn't a relational database.  You'll have to write your own DAL.

Comment: what is DAL (raw guess, data access language, something like that?)

Comment: It's a Data Access Layer.  Presuming you're using an n-tier architecture, it's the layer responsible for dealing with the database directly.

Answer (score 2):

Also, PlayOrm for cassandra has a 1.2 and 2.0 playframework plugin and automatically reloads as playframework reloads so annotations take affect immediately in development.  Lastly, it has the in-memory nosql db implementation as well so you can just start playframework without cassandra and work your butt off efficiently and connect to cassandra in QA and production.

Answer (score 1):

See if it helps, a sample application hosted at github:
https://github.com/firekat/play-kundera

-Vivek

Comment: thanks for answer. If you have an example with hector it will be really more usefull for me.

Comment: I tried this example. But I got several exception again and again when I tried to change some parts of it.[PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "xmlns".]   [PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Duplicate persistence-units for name: cassandra_pu. verify your persistence.xml file]